# Xampp control panel is blank

Tags: xampp, invisible, controlpanel

[Failure of xampp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w5xEc.jpg)

My xampp turns up invisible whenever i start it via control panel or any other way.
Is there a fix for this?

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem but I found a way that worked for me.
Hover over the XAMPP icon in the taskbar and right click on the preview. Click 'maximise'.

Answer (score 0):

Since you've provided basically no information at all, there are only two things I can think of:

- Restarting your pc
- Updating XAMPP
- Reinstalling XAMPP

If this doesn't work, I have no clue what would.